Shared memory among forked processes c++
I am writing a c++ program and I want a program where there are two processes (running with fork()) and they both share a common list and an interprocess mutex is there to guard the shared list modifications from each process. How can I declare the list and the mutex so that they are shared among processes?
I can use boost library if needed (and if it makes things easier)

boost.interprocess provides portable shared memory support and allocators on said memory for STL containers

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The absolute simplest way is to reopen after fork. That way you never risk any unspecified (or undefined) behavior.
Complete example: Live On Coliru
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace Shared {
    namespace bc  = boost::container;
    namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

    using Segment                     = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using Manager                     = Segment::segment_manager;
    template <typename T> using Alloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Manager>>;

    template <typename T> using Vector = bc::vector<T, Alloc<T>>;
    template <typename K, typename V, typename C = std::less<K>>
    using Map    = bc::map<K, V, C, Alloc<std::pair<K const, V>>>;
    using String = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;

    struct MyData {
        using allocator_type = Alloc<MyData>;

        template <typename A> MyData(A&& alloc) : data_(std::forward<A>(alloc)) {}

        size_t count() const {
            for (std::lock_guard lk(mx_);;)
                return data_.size();
        }

        void set(std::string_view key, std::initializer_list<int> values) {
            std::lock_guard lk(mx_);

            if (auto it = data_.find(key); it != data_.end())
                it->second.assign(values.begin(), values.end());
            else
                data_.emplace(key, std::move(values));
        }

        void remove(std::string_view key) {
            std::lock_guard lk(mx_);
            data_.erase(key);
        }

        void print() const {
            std::lock_guard lk(mx_);
            for (auto& [key, values] : data_)
                fmt::print("  {}: {}\n", key, values);
        }

      private:
        mutable bip::interprocess_mutex mx_;

        struct KeyCmp : std::less<std::string_view> { using is_transparent = void; };
        Map<String, Vector<int>, KeyCmp> data_;
    };
} // namespace Shared

static constexpr auto SegmentName = "MySharedMemory";

int parent() {
    using namespace Shared;

    Segment segment(bip::open_only, SegmentName);
    auto [myData, N] = segment.find<MyData>("MyData");
    assert(N == 1); // not an array

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    myData->set("foo", {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    myData->set("bar", {6, 7, 8, 9, 10});
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    myData->set("foo", {5, 4, 3, 2, 1});
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    myData->remove("bar");

    std::cout << "parent done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int child() {
    using namespace Shared;

    Segment segment(bip::open_only, SegmentName);
    auto [myData, N] = segment.find<MyData>("MyData");
    assert(N == 1); // not an array

    for (int i : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
        std::cout << "child foo #" << i << ": " << myData->count() << "\n";
        myData->print();
    }
    std::cout << "child done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    {
        using namespace Shared;
        Segment::device_type::remove(SegmentName);
        Segment segment(bip::create_only, SegmentName, 64 << 20ul); // 64MiB
        segment.find_or_construct<MyData>("MyData")(segment.get_segment_manager());
    }
    return fork()? parent() : child();
}

Printing:


Fixed the online demo on Coliru https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52f4f4b529a1a1aa (using mapped file and smaller size for compatibility)
